# Extract MD&A section from parsed 10-K in folder on desktop

Tags: utf-8, extract, finance

I've got folders (with unique company names) of parsed 10ks in a datacollection folder on my desktop. I want to extract the MD&A sections of the files and store them in my datacollection folder.

I used part of the codes in here: https://github.com/rflugum/10K-MDA-Section/blob/master/MDA%20Extractor.py and modified it.

However, I ran into a problem and for every doc i printed I got the return statement  "NO MD&A" if I run the codes in python2. If I run the codes in python3 and I get the return statement 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte in '...' position. I think there might be a syntax error in my codes.

Can you kindly have a look at my codes?

```
import re
import sys
import os
import nltk
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer


item7={}
item7[1]="item 7\. managements discussion and analysis"
item7[2]="item 7\.managements discussion and analysis"
item7[3]="item7\. managements discussion and analysis"
item7[4]="item7\.managements discussion and analysis"
item7[5]="item 7\. management discussion and analysis"
item7[6]="item 7\.management discussion and analysis"
item7[7]="item7\. management discussion and analysis"
item7[8]="item7\.management discussion and analysis"
item7[9]="item 7 managements discussion and analysis"
item7[10]="item 7managements discussion and analysis"
item7[11]="item7 managements discussion and analysis"
item7[12]="item7managements discussion and analysis"
item7[13]="item 7 management discussion and analysis"
item7[14]="item 7management discussion and analysis"
item7[15]="item7 management discussion and analysis"
item7[16]="item7management discussion and analysis"
item7[17]="item 7: managements discussion and analysis"
item7[18]="item 7:managements discussion and analysis"
item7[19]="item7: managements discussion and analysis"
item7[20]="item7:managements discussion and analysis"
item7[21]="item 7: management discussion and analysis"
item7[22]="item 7:management discussion and analysis"
item7[23]="item7: management discussion and analysis"
item7[24]="item7:management discussion and analysis"


item8={}
item8[1]="item 8\. financial statements"
item8[2]="item 8\.financial statements"
item8[3]="item8\. financial statements"
item8[4]="item8\.financial statements"
item8[5]="item 8 financial statements"
item8[6]="item 8financial statements"
item8[7]="item8 financial statements"
item8[8]="item8financial statements"
item8[9]="item 8a\. financial statements"
item8[10]="item 8a\.financial statements"
item8[11]="item8a\. financial statements"
item8[12]="item8a\.financial statements"
item8[13]="item 8a financial statements"
item8[14]="item 8afinancial statements"
item8[15]="item8a financial statements"
item8[16]="item8afinancial statements"
item8[17]="item 8\. consolidated financial statements"
item8[18]="item 8\.consolidated financial statements"
item8[19]="item8\. consolidated financial statements"
item8[20]="item8\.consolidated financial statements"
item8[21]="item 8 consolidated  financial statements"
item8[22]="item 8consolidated financial statements"
item8[23]="item8 consolidated  financial statements"
item8[24]="item8consolidated financial statements"
item8[25]="item 8a\. consolidated financial statements"
item8[26]="item 8a\.consolidated financial statements"
item8[27]="item8a\. consolidated financial statements"
item8[28]="item8a\.consolidated financial statements"
item8[29]="item 8a consolidated financial statements"
item8[30]="item 8aconsolidated financial statements"
item8[31]="item8a consolidated financial statements"
item8[32]="item8aconsolidated financial statements"
item8[33]="item 8\. audited financial statements"
item8[34]="item 8\.audited financial statements"
item8[35]="item8\. audited financial statements"
item8[36]="item8\.audited financial statements"
item8[37]="item 8 audited financial statements"
item8[38]="item 8audited financial statements"
item8[39]="item8 audited financial statements"
item8[40]="item8audited financial statements"
item8[41]="item 8: financial statements"
item8[42]="item 8:financial statements"
item8[43]="item8: financial statements"
item8[44]="item8:financial statements"
item8[45]="item 8: consolidated financial statements"
item8[46]="item 8:consolidated financial statements"
item8[47]="item8: consolidated financial statements"
item8[48]="item8:consolidated financial statements"

look={" see ", " refer to ", " included in "," contained in "}

a={}
c={}

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/lucy/Desktop/summer/SummaryDataFile"):
    for file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, file), "r") as auto:
            for line in auto: 
                lstr1=line.lower()
                for j in range(1,25):
                    a[j]=[]
                    for m in re.finditer(item7[j], lstr1):
                        if not m:
                            break
                        else:
                            substr1=lstr1[m.start()-20:m.start()]
                            if not any(s in substr1 for s in look):   
                                #print substr1
                                b=m.start()
                                a[j].append(b)
                #print i

                list1=[]
                for value in a.values():
                    for thing1 in value:
                        list1.append(thing1)
                list1.sort()
                list1.append(len(lstr1))
                #print list1

                for j in range(1,49):
                    c[j]=[]
                    for m in re.finditer(item8[j], lstr1):
                        if not m:
                            break
                        else:
                            substr1=lstr1[m.start()-20:m.start()]
                            if not any(s in substr1 for s in look):   
                                #print substr1
                                b=m.start()
                                c[j].append(b)
                list2=[]
                for value in c.values():
                    for thing2 in value:
                        list2.append(thing2)
                list2.sort()

                locations={}
                if list2==[]:
                    print("NO MD&A")
                else:
                    if list1==[]:
                        print("NO MD&A")
                    else:
                        for k0 in range(len(list1)):
                            locations[k0]=[]
                            locations[k0].append(list1[k0])
                        for k0 in range(len(locations)):
                            for item in range(len(list2)):
                                if locations[k0][0]<=list2[item]:
                                    locations[k0].append(list2[item])
                                    break
                            if len(locations[k0])==1:
                                del locations[k0]

                if locations=={}:
                    LOG=file+".txt"
                    with open(LOG,'a') as f:
                        f.write(str(file)+"\t"+"0\n")#changed from filenum to file
                        f.close()
                else:
                    sections=0
                    for k0 in range(len(locations)): 
                        substring2=str1[locations[k0][0]:locations[k0][1]]
                        substring3=substring2.split()
                        if len(substring3)>250:
                            sections=sections+1
                            with open(Filer,'a') as f:
                                f.write("<SECTION>\n")
                                f.write(substring2+"\n")
                                f.write("</SECTION>\n")
                                f.close()
                    with open(LOG,'a') as f:
                            f.write(str(file)+"\t"+str(sections)+"\n")
                            f.close()
                print(file)
```

Comment: If there was a syntax error, then you'd get an error and your code would not run. It appears that it is in fact running, so it's not a syntax error. Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger to see what's happening and why it's not working as expected?

Comment: Your question is way too complicated for your specific issue. You should just pick one sample 10k filing and show only the portion of the code intended to capture the MD&A section. This way readers can try to figure out what is wrong with that specific part.